# Is it possible to use PowerPoint Themes as Reveal Theme in Quarto?

Tags: themes, powerpoint, reveal.js, quarto

I was wondering if it is possible to use a PowerPoint theme as a Reveal theme in a `revealjs` presentation? Here is an example of a built-in [theme](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zkj2z714r1nz1berz6tyc/Powerpoint-Theme.pptx?dl=0&rlkey=lov03yoyoayv79cggfp99mwav) in PowerPoint:

[image]

So is it possible to use this in a Revealjs presentation as the theme?

Comment: Legally possible?  Most likely yes. If that's not the question, please elaborate.

Comment: Hi @SteveRindsberg, Glad to hear! My question is more about how to implement the theme of Powerpoint in my reveal presentation created in Quarto. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: Afraid not. I don't even know what Quarto is, so can't help with this one.

Comment: Here you can find more information about what [Quarto](https://quarto.org) is.

Comment: The documentation turns into what apparently is a rabbit-hole of unknown depth if you try to find out how to use themes. Life's too short ... but if all you need is an image to serve as a background, then it's simple. Create a blank PPT slide based on the theme you want, choose File | Save As | File of Type:  {whatever format makes Quarto happy ... PNG, JPG, etc}.